# Android device directory not creating when i set target api as 29

Tags: android, cordova

i have a mobile app in cordova , in that i create directory , if i use Target Api 28, it will create folder, in same time if set Target  Api as 29 ,directory never creating, i am using following code to create directory in internal storage.

```
 if (device.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
        } else {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
        }
        
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        var entry = "";
        if (device.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
            entry = fileSystem;
        } else {
            entry = fileSystem.root;
        }
        entry.getDirectory("smfolder", {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
    };



    function onError(e) {
        alert("Fail to get folder");
    };
```

This is config.xml screenshot : http://prntscr.com/w53qgh
When i upload in Play Store , it will ask to set Target Api level as 29, then only can upload, so i need to set API as 29, is there any thing need to add in config or android manifest file ? or need to add permission to use API 29.

Appreciate your assistance since i have been stuck in this for few days now.

Regards,

Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not a Cordova expert, it seems that the issue is because of [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) introduced as part of API 29 (Android 10)

It adds some restrictions on how your app can read/write to file system. However, as a work-around, you can opt-out of Scoped Storage to work just like API 28.

Just add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest file's application tag to opt-out of scoped storage. It should solve your problem.

Make sure your compileSdkVersion is set to 29 to use this attribute.

Please note that if you target API 30 (Android 11), this flag will be ignored by the system and you have to make your app compatible with scoped storage.

More on: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply, if i add that tag in manifest , i will get build error, so after that i cant build apk.here i attach error screenshot : http://prntscr.com/w5a6kq

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your manifest file?

Comment: yes, here i share screenshot of manifest file - http://prntscr.com/w5s0xn

Comment: and one more thing, without that tag i can build apk file, so no problem with Android_Home and Path in Environment variable which i set  i think.

Comment: Can you make sure your compileSdkVersion is also set to 29? If not, change it to 29 and recompile, your manifest file looks fine.

Comment: manually need to set , if yes , where need to set ? in build.gradle file it will assign automatically from androidmanifest file and android version (CLI) i used 6.1.0

Comment: hi is this correct which i set environment variables
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk;
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
APPDATA=C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Roaming
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android; physical path Ss http://prntscr.com/w7rlhx sdv Ss http://prntscr.com/w7rr4p

Comment: All your paths look fine to me. The only thing you're supposed to do is change the compileSdkVersion to 29. As I said earilier, I am not a cordova expert, but this usually can be changed from build.gradle file.

Comment: hi thank u very much, i manually changed 29 in build.gradle, it works fine, but why it not auto detect installed version from Android_home and Path even all path mention correctly in Environment variable . Anyway thanks to support

Comment: Great! An upvote to the answer would be much appriciated because it will help others know the reliability of the answer.